# Am I getting a segmentation fault due to an incorrect realloc?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc

```
struct model
{
    char *cam;
    int *to_location, *go_location;
    int to_count, go_count;
    int length, size;
};

struct model *
initialize(int l)
{
    struct model *c;
    c = (struct model *)malloc(sizeof(struct model));
    assert(c != NULL);
    c->length = l;
    c->size = 2 * l;
    c->cam = (char *)malloc(2 * l * sizeof(char));
    assert(c->cam != NULL);
    c->to_location = (int *)malloc(l * sizeof(int));
    assert(c->to_location != NULL);
    c->go_location = (int *)malloc(l * sizeof(int));
    assert(c->go_location != NULL);
    return c;
}

void 
shuffle(struct model *current, struct model *future, int to, int g)
{
    int i1, k, d1;
    char init[100000];
    current->to_count = 0;
    current->go_count = 0;
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < g; i1++)
    {
        init[i1] = 'G';
    }
    for (i1 = g; i1 < g + to; i1++)
    {
        init[i1] = 'T';
    }
    for (i1 = g + to; i1 < current->length; i1++)
    {
        init[i1] = '.';
    }
    for(i1 = 0; i1 < future->length; i1++)
    {
        d1 = rand() % current->length;
        current->cam[i1] = init[d1];
        if (current->cam[i1] == 'T')
        {
            current->to_location[current->to_count] = i1;
            current->to_count = current->to_count + 1;
        }
        if (current->cam[i1] == 'G')
        {
            current->go_location[current->go_count] = i1;
            current->go_count = current->go_count + 1;
        }
        for (k = d1; k < current->length; k++)
        {
            init[k] = init[k + 1];
        }
        current->length = current->length - 1;
    }
    current->length = future->length;
}

void 
display(struct model *current)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n<");
    current->to_count = 0;
    current->go_count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < current->length; i++) 
    {
        if (current->cam[i] == 'T')
        {
            current->to_location[current->to_count] = i;
            current->to_count = current->to_count + 1;
        }
        else if (current->cam[i] == 'G')
        {
            current->go_location[current->go_count] = i;
            current->go_count = current->go_count + 1;
        }
        printf("%c", current->cam[i]);
    }
    printf(">\n");
    printf("\nThe total number of to's are %d, and the total number of gos      are %d. The length is %d\n", current->to_count, current->go_count, current->length);
}

void 
insert(struct model *current, struct model *future)
{
    int j, k;
    k = rand() % (current->length + 1);
    current->length = current->length + 1;
    for (j = current->length; j > k; j--)
    {
        future->cam[j] = future->cam[j - 1];
    }
    future->cam[k] = 'T';
    future->size = 2 * current->length;
    future->cam = (char *)realloc(future->cam, future->size * sizeof(char));
    assert(future->cam != NULL);
    current->size = 2 * current->length;
    current->cam = (char *)realloc(current->cam, current->size * sizeof(char));
    assert(current->cam != NULL);
}

int 
main()
{
    int l, to, go, i, k1, k2, j;
    l = 100; //l,go,to are positive
    go = 20;
    to = 20; //go+to cannot be greater than l
    struct model *current = initialize(l), *future = initialize(l);
    shuffle(current, future, to, go);
    display(current);
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < current->length; j++)
        {
            future->cam[j] = current->cam[j];
        }
        insert(current, future);
        for (j = 0; j < current->length; j++)
        {
            current->cam[j] = future->cam[j];
        }
        display(current);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to find out the reason for a segmentation fault. I checked to see if I had implemented realloc correctly but from what I can tell there might not be a mistake there. the segmentation fault occurs after `current->length` reaches 281, so reallocation may be occurring uptill there as the initial size is 200 but why does it stop after that?

Comment: Did you know that compilers ignore white spaces? You don't need to write unreadable code like that, you can write easy to read code with no effort.

Comment: This code is unreadable. If you don't even care to properly indent your code, so that it's readable, why should anyone bother to try to figure out what's wrong with it?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to help you find the problem?

Comment: My apologies, I will make the changes. Can you please give me a reference on how should I indent this?

Comment: @kaylum No, I don't know how to use one. Could you give me a link to something from where I could learn?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah gcc

Comment: Does this help? http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/

Comment: this details how to examine memory in `gdb`: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html

Comment: I suspect you are writing out of bounds of your array current size

Comment: try adding #include directives for <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h>, <assert.h>

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thank you

Comment: @M.M but shouldn't realloc take care of that?

Comment: @GroovyDotCom Yes, I did include them in my program. I have skipped them here to reduce the size of the program

Comment: @M.M Wouldn't the array size be increased in every cycle of the loop if the realloc works? Initially, it sets the array size as 200 but then it adds beyond 200 as well but breaks at 281 each time.

Comment: debug your program to check array bounds each time you write

Comment: future->cam takes on the value 0x136 at some point. That is not a legal pointer so it crashes.

Comment: It is dying because you are not reallocing to_location and yet you write to it all the way up to current->length which gets bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `initialize()` you:

```
c->cam = (char *)malloc(2 * l * sizeof(char));
assert(c->cam != NULL);
c->to_location = (int *)malloc(l * sizeof(int));
assert(c->to_location != NULL);
c->go_location = (int *)malloc(l * sizeof(int));
assert(c->go_location != NULL);
```

And then in `insert()` you:

```
current->length = current->length + 1;
....
future->size = 2 * current->length;
future->cam = (char *)realloc(future->cam, future->size * sizeof(char));
assert(future->cam != NULL);
current->size = 2 * current->length;
current->cam = (char *)realloc(current->cam, current->size * sizeof(char));
```

And then in `display()` you:

```
current->to_count = 0;
current->go_count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < current->length; i++)
...
        current->to_location[current->to_count] = i;
        current->to_count = current->to_count + 1;
...
        current->go_location[current->go_count] = i;
        current->go_count = current->go_count + 1;
```

A similar thing also happens in `shuffle()`

So you write to to to_location from 0 up to current->length and current->length continues getting bigger because of insert() and yet to_location does NOT get bigger so as soon as current->length is increased you write past the end of the to_location array and clobber something important - eventually killing the program.